# Views Exposed Hierarchical Term Reference Autocomplete

Tags: ajax, views

I am trying to get the widget from this module https://www.drupal.org/project/term_ref_autocomplete to be available as the autocomplete widget for a taxonomy exposed filter on a view

So far I have nothing useful and I'm not sure which is the best way to do it.

Should it be a new filter with a custom plugin in a new module?, Am I going to have to duplicate all the code from the original module ? Can I hook_form_alter on the views_exposed_form ??

Any ideas / help very much appreciated

Thanks